# Change Text in Visual Studio using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

As you might know,Visual Studio's Find and Replace feature allows us to use Regular Expression but I don't know how to change something like this :

```
Math.round((document.getElementById('selectedproductPrixdock').value*document.getElementById('addxdock').value)*100)/100
```

to this one :

```
(Math.round((document.getElementById('selectedproductPrixdock').value*document.getElementById('addxdock').value)*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

There are too much code like this on the page and changing them one by one is a big hassle.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: We need a bit more context -- is the first line an entire line, or in the middle of the line? How similar are the other target lines to this one?

Comment: Hi, the inner part may differ sometimes but the regex should not care about the inner part,all I need is to add `(` at the beginning and `).toFixed(2)` at the end of the given string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a very good candidate for regular expressions, as those are used to find/replace **patterns**.  Deriving a pattern from this text would probably be a waste of time.

I'd just do this:

```
string s = "...some text...";
string toBeReplaced = "Math.round((document.getElementById('selectedproductPrixdock').value*document.getElementById('addxdock').value)*100)/100";
string replacement = "(" + toBeReplaced + ").toFixed(2)";
string result = s.Replace(toBeReplaced, replacement);
```

**EDIT:**

After re-reading your question, knowing each individual ID would make that tougher.  Here's a Regex that should work:

```
string s = "...some text...";
string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"Math\.round\(\(document\.getElementById\('.+'\)\.value*document\.getElementById\('.+'\).value\)*100\)/100", "($0).toFixed(2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

How similar are the things you're trying to match?

If they're all identical except for the inner arguments, then

```
s/Math.round\(\(document.getElementById\('(.*?)'\).value*document.getElementById\('(.*?)'\).value\)*100\)\/100/\(Math.round\(\(document.getElementById\('$1'\).value*document.getElementById\('$2'\).value\)*100\)\/100\).toFixed\(2\)/g
```

Replacing $1 and $2 with whatever VS uses to fill in backreferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking too much of regex in general.

In related news, you would likely have an easier time refactoring if you didn't pack fifty instructions into a single line.